# "he has almost nothing" or "he hasn't almost anything"?

Tags: adverbs, translation, negation

So, I'm helping a friend of mine who has just started learning English. 
He wants to say "He has almost nothing to eat in his cupboards" using the negative form. Is "he hasn't almost anything to eat in his cupboards" correct as well? It seems to me that it just doesn't work. Are there any rules about the use of ***almost*** in such cases?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It wouldn't be very idiomatic.  And I question whether "almost" can legitimately modify "anything" in this context.

Comment: *He has **hardly anything** to eat in his cupboard.* This is a matter of "positive / negative polarity". @HotLicks: You can say ***almost anything*** given the right context!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - There are some people who will say almost anything in any context!

Comment: @HotLicks: Is [*You **can't** buy hardly anything*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+can%27t+buy+hardly+anything%22) an example of "emphatic colloquial double negation"? If so, how do we classify [*can't buy hardly nothin'*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22can%27t+buy+hardly+nothin%22)?

Comment: Not in the US. Don't know about UK, but I'd be surprised to hear it. In the US, _has not_ doesn't contract when _have_ means 'possess'; only when it's an auxiliary verb, like the perfect _He hasn't ever been there_. When _have_ means 'possess', _Do_-Support is required: _He doesn't have the virus_, but not *_He hasn't the virus_.

Comment: By the way, _almost nothing_ ***is*** "the negative form", so your friend's question is a little strange. What is "the negative form" supposed to mean?

Comment: I assume he means he want a “He doesn’t have” form instead of a “He has” form.  He doesn’t have anything to eat.  He doesn’t have much [left] in his cupboards.

Comment: In the UK, 'he hasn't a bean', 'he hasn't a penny to his name' are fine: the use of 'hasn't'  with 'has' = 'possess' is not totally outlawed. However, these are exceptions; 'he hasn't £5' would never be heard – 'he hasn't got £5' is idiomatic. And 'he hasn't almost anything' sounds like a poor line by Goofy or someone pedantically and dodgily  correcting someone who's just said "He has hardly anything."

Answer (score 1):

Hasn't almost anything sounds wrong in many ways.
1) Hasn't can't be used here because has is denoting possession of something.
2) Almost anything doesn't seem right because you're using it in a negative sense.
3) Even if you don't use the contraction hasn't, it's not right. Because, you can't say "has not anything", it should be "has nothing".
But "He has almost nothing to eat in his cupboards" is perfectly fine.

Comment: (1) He hasn't a clue? They haven't a chance?

Comment: [Earth hath not anything to show more fair](https://poets.org/poem/composed-upon-westminster-bridge-september-3-1802)? I don't think that the language has changed that much in the last 200 years.